# Phoenix CsvBulkLoadTool error while running from Windows

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I want to put csv data file to HBase table using `CsvBulkLoadTool` from Java.

HBase and Phoenix are running on Ubuntu VM.

When I run `CsvBulkLoadTool.run()` from Windows I get next exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pathname /C:/Users/My_User/.m2/repository/org/apache/htrace/htrace-core/3.1.0-incubating/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar from hdfs://vm:9000/C:/Users/My_User/.m2/repository/org/apache/htrace/htrace-core/3.1.0-incubating/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar is not a valid DFS filename.
```

By the way, when I `java -jar` my sample app running on Ubuntu VM, I get nex exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://vm:9000/usr/local/phoenix-samples-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

where `/usr/local/phoenix-samples-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` is actual jar file location on Ubuntu vm.

I used `CsvBulkLoadTool` samples from [here](https://programtalk.com/java-api-usage-examples/org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.CsvBulkLoadTool/).

Also, when I'm using plain JDBC for connecting and populating table through Phoenix - everything works.

Comment: I thought the CSV had to on the instance within hdfs in hbase in order to run? is that the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSVBulkloadTool should be run as `hadoop jar`.

So I should run:
`hadoop jar my-application-with-CSVBulkloadTool.jar`